# Camel : integration tests of asynchronous routes

Tags: java, asynchronous, testing, apache-camel, integration-testing

I have an application using apache camel which has a full coverage of unit tests using the great camel testing support. These tests cover each parts of camel routes and work perfectly.

I now want to write integration tests that do not mocks endpoints called by Camel. For example, I want to test a part of the application that behaves like this:

1. Receive a request on a rest endpoint and reply 202
2. Transform the message and publish it on activemq
3. Read the message from activemq, transform it and push it to a rest endpoint

The test look like this

```
// start activemq, applications, etc...
WebTarget target = //initialize a JAX RS webtarget
DTO data = // generate some datas
Response r = target .path("url").request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(Entity.json(data));
Assert.assertEquals(r.getStatus(), 202);
// stop activemq, applications, etc...
```

This part works great.

Now the thing is : if the endpoint replies with a 500 code, I log the error in a mongo database. I want my integration test to check this.

I tried this :

```
// start activemq, applications, etc...
WebTarget target = //initialize a JAX RS webtarget
DTO data = // generate some datas that generate an error
Response r = target .path("url").request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(Entity.json(data));
Assert.assertEquals(r.getStatus(), 202);
Thread.sleep(1000);
assertErrors(1); // check in mongo if error is written
// stop activemq, applications, etc...
```

I don't like the `Thread.sleep(1000)`.

My questions are :

1. Is there a way to know if Camel have finished processing all the messages ?
2. Does it make sense to test the mongo result in this case as it is already covered by a unit test on the portion of the route ?

Thanks for advice.

Comment: For the first item, look into using Camel's [NotifyBuilder](http://camel.apache.org/notifybuilder.html).

Comment: I didn't know about this thing. Look just perfect !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mdnghtblue mention in comment, NotifyBuilder is the right answer

http://camel.apache.org/notifybuilder.html